# Associated table SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
Racer( racerID, racerName)
Race (raceID, raceName)
RaceJoinRacer(raceID, racersID)
```

I can't figure out the sql statement that will retrieve which "racer" have attended which "race".

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT racerName, raceName 
FROM Racer, Race 
JOIN RaceJoinRacer 
    ON RaceJoinRacer.raceID= Race.raceID
```

Comment: Do you want to show racers that have attended no races?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing implicit and explicit join syntax.  Don't use commas in your `FROM` clause.  Instead, use two `JOIN` statements, which imply `INNER JOIN` in MySQL.

```
SELECT
  racerName, 
  raceName 
FROM
  Race 
  JOIN RaceJoinRacer ON RaceJoinRacer.raceID = Race.raceID
  JOIN Racer ON RaceJoinRacer.racersID = Racer.racerID
```

If you want to include racers from the `Racer` table who have not participated in any races, use a `LEFT JOIN` between `Racer` and `RaceJoinRacer` instead:

```
SELECT
  racerName, 
  raceName 
FROM
  Racer
  LEFT JOIN Racer ON RaceJoinRacer.racersID = Racer.racerID
  JOIN RaceJoinRacer ON RaceJoinRacer.raceID = Race.raceID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   racerName, 
   Race.raceName 
FROM Racer 
   JOIN RaceJoinRacer ON Racer.racerID = RaceJoinRacer.racersID 
   JOIN Race ON Race.RaceID = RaceJoinRacer.RaceID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.racerName, c.raceName 
FROM Racer r
inner join RaceJoinRacer rj ON r.racerID = rj.racerID 
inner join race on c on rj.raceid = c.raceid
```